# GLIBCXX_3.4.XX & CXXABI_1.3.XX missing

Tags: apt, wine, playonlinux, lutris

After installing Xilinx ISE 14.7, it seems as though several programs are searching in it's directories for the libstdc++.so.6 &  file but are unable to use it. I'm not sure how to get them to look for it in other places. I had this problem while trying to run League of Legends Garena as per the instructions given on the LeagueofLinux subreddit.

After looking around online, i found out that I have to enter the file path to the PATH variable on the grub menu, but does it mean that I need to add every single file path that requires either GLIB and CXXAIB to it?

The setup method I followed for League of Legends - Garena on the subreddit - https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflinux/comments/mm45tm/playing_on_garena/

```
    apt search nvidia-driver
apt: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by apt)
apt: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0)
apt: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0)
apt: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0)
apt: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0)
apt: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0)
apt: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0)
apt: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0)
apt: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.7' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.6.0)
apt: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.6.0)
apt: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.6.0)
apt: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.6.0)
apt: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.6.0)
apt: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.6.0)
apt: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.6.0)
apt: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.6.0)
apt: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.6.0)
apt: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.6.0)
apt: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.6.0)
apt: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.6.0)
```

This is the output after running League of Legends - Garena on Lutris:

```
--garena-plus-token=d2hyR6g+6xtZfdWSiZ2N65XdSeKVlNhDkHW6qp3fNdiWHd+ukhGI5Sxez/5WmZO52fLTjKKZVt26eLCoantnI6YvjVICFBEaT4zUbvXXo1L/Z4bz5lBIi2tU1FocCqd66pFyvl1UBAM7mnA9tBhXUW9mwnng8qoNLYOZcdF6dZIXvwdJqRLdPxVksLI99BSjOgAHLfpO/1JwkLR1GV4w8SQ00l4pyZcJE9EHtbq8sltE05/dzsuta9wPQszXKzfvc22Zg4NLoriX3CNWnKTuHp/yRhV8gloZ1GiJ9CuFaL5YscVV1wkBL28yFCImjhKfFaHBTakW/7BkWnIE3wlhMQ== --region=SG -- --locale=en_SG --landing-token=d3f99e7829e7d1326339adb80a228702b76c3a93c66745cc52328f0665ab3e88 --servers.chat.chat_host=sg1.chat.si.riotgames.com --servers.lcds.lcds_host=prod.lol.garenanow.com --servers.lcds.login_queue_url=https://lq.lol.garenanow.com/login-queue/rest/queues/lol --region=SG --parent-client=GarenaPC
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  60
  Current serial number in output stream:  59
2021-05-12 20:31:15,525: glxinfo call failed: Command '['glxinfo', '-B']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
2021-05-12 20:31:15,526: No available glxinfo output
2021-05-12 20:31:15,526: Invalid glxinfo received
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/games/lutris", line 52, in <module>
    from lutris.gui.application import Application  # pylint: disable=no-name-in-module
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/gui/application.py", line 41, in <module>
    from lutris.gui.installerwindow import InstallerWindow
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/gui/installerwindow.py", line 17, in <module>
    from lutris.installer import interpreter
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/installer/interpreter.py", line 14, in <module>
    from lutris.installer.installer import LutrisInstaller
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/installer/installer.py", line 16, in <module>
    from lutris.services import get_services
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/services/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from lutris.services.gog import GOGService
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/services/gog.py", line 9, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.66)
```

Edit : I'm currently using the following system specs -

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Intel i5-9300H
Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650

Comment: Maybe starting with your OS & release may help (ie. what software stack are you using?)

Comment: Did you modify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` during your installation/setup of Xilinx?

Comment: So while installing Xilinx, I entered the following under the `nano .bashrc` menu:
`source /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/settings64.sh`

Comment: @DarkShaman and does `/opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/settings64.sh` mess with library search variables like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at all? if so, perhaps it's not something that you should generally source from your .bashrc

Comment: I don't completely understand your question, but on listing out the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable, there are definitely many PATHs for Xilinx. Is my only option to get rid of Xilinx if I wanna run anything normally?